# Line integral confirmation and Geometric interpretation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have $$\int_{C}(z - \bar{z})dz$$ where $C = \{z \; : \; |z-1| =2\}$

So I parametrize $C$ by letting $z = 2e^{it} + 1 = 2\cos(t)+ 1 + 2i\sin(t)$ and let $x = 2\cos(t)+1$ and $y = 2\sin(t)$, for $t \in [0,2\pi]$

$dz = dx + idy = (-2\sin(t) + 2i\cos(t))dt$

Also note that $z - \bar{z} = (x+iy) - (x-iy) = 2iy = 4i\sin(t)$
Therefore, we then have

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(4i\sin(t))(-2\sin(t) + 2i\cos(t))dt$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(-8i\sin^2(t) - 8\cos(t)\sin(t))dt$$

$$ = -8i\pi$$

What is the geometric meaning of this result? We have a contour, a closed curve that is, for which we are integrating over. Are we finding the area under this curve? What does this geometrically mean especially since the answer is negative?

Comment: ... yes, I think so. $|z-z_0|= \rho$ means a circle centered at $z_0$ with radius $\rho$. So, expressing it with Euler's Formula would be: $\rho e^{i\theta} + z_0$. :(

Comment: @Chappers  I have updated my post appropriately

Comment: It's not just negative, it's *imaginary*; which should not be unexpected on the complex plane.

Comment: The negative symbol is there though. Just being imaginary would be: $8i$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's going on here is that
$$ \int_C (z-\bar{z}) dz = 2i\int_C y \,( \, dx+i \, dy) $$
Now, $2y \, dy$ has a well-known antiderivative, $y^2$, which means you can just evaluate that bit of the integral at each end of the contour, giving zero:
$$ \int_C 2y \, dy = [y^2]_{\text{ends of }C} = 0, $$
since $C$ is closed, so both ends are the same point. The other term,
$$ 2i \int_C y \, dx, $$
you can recognise as the area under a curve, but because you have a circle, you cover the top half-circle going left along the top part of the circle and the bottom half going the right along the other, so it adds up to the total area of the circle. The reason for the minus sign is you go anticlockwise, so the top and bottom area both contribute negatively.

To compute it more efficiently, if $z=1+2e^{it}$, $\bar{z} = 1+2e^{-it}$, and $dz=2ie^{it} \, dt$, so
$$ \int_C (z-\bar{z}) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} 2(e^{it}-e^{-it}) 2ie^{it} \, dt = 0 - 4i \cdot 2\pi = -8i\pi $$

Comment: I am pretty confused on how to geometrically view this. To my understanding, line integrals are integrals for which find the area under a certain curve or contour. That is, from the curve draw in the (usually) x,y plane to a $f(x,y)$ in the $x,y,z$ plane which usually looks like a big sheet of paper.  Please view my attempt at interpreting it that way: http://i.imgur.com/B19V4lh.jpg My issue is: I do not know how to draw said 'sheet of paper'. That is, $f(t)=4i\sin(t)$ isn't a plane, but rather an occelating line.

Comment: In other words, My current understanding is that our curve/contour is drawn in the, usually, xy-plane and the line integral is the area of the 'curtain' or 'region' made by connecting the curve to the plane above it f(x,y) in the x,y,z space. I am partically confused for how to do that for

Comment: You can't really talk about area in the same way for complex functions, since you can't visualise it in three dimensions. The negative, as I said above, is a consequence of going round the loop anticlockwise. Once you have it in the form $\int y \, dx$, then you can see what the picture is, but notice that in this form it looks much more like the ordinary area under a curve in 2D than underneath a line above the complex plane. You are still doing a sum, but it's a sum of complex numbers, so it doesn't just look like a rectangle, but more like placing vectors head-to-tail.